# Java regex. How to get 3 different parts of text?

Tags: java, regex, regular-language

I have this very long String in java

> 200/23/Ne7WoRK/3045022100d62568e28cb58b4a5308750e63e4690c4538ddc18>a9dc6075d02f7b4f942c4aa0220587350e7db1f4380a36ebb441906833563d32a62c4a>03cf334295615f981c47e

What I want to achieve is to get:

> Bid: 200
>
> Username: Ne7WoRK
>
> Signature: 3045022100d62568e28cb58b4a5308750e63e4690c4538ddc18a9dc6075d02f7b4f942c4aa0220587350e7db1f4380a36ebb441906833563d32a62c4a03cf334295615f981c47e

I need 3 regular expressions that will help me get separate Strings of the bid value, username and Signature. I am not sure how to achieve that. My attempt to solve this was with the following regular expression

> \b.*/\b

However, this regular expression matches the whole 3 subparts and gives an output of this

> 200/23/Ne7WoRK/

I am not sure how to create 3 different regular expressions where:

1. The first one will match any digits from the start of the string up to the first "/" symbol. Giving String of 200
2. The second one will match any character from the second "/" symbol up to the third "/" symbol. Giving Ne7WoRK
3. The third one should match everything from the third "/" up to the end of the string. Giving the long number of - 3045022100d62568e28cb58b4a5308750e63e4690c4538ddc18a9dc6075d02f7b4f942c4aa0220587350e7db1f4380a36ebb441906833563d32a62c4a03cf334295615f981c47e

Comment: You should not ask questions about regular expressions when you don't know yet whether they are the best tool for the job. In this case they are not, since a simple `String.split` is enough.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can split it

```
String a = "200/23/Ne7WoRK/3045022100d62568e28cb58b4a5308750e63e4690c4538ddc18>a9dc6075d02f7b4f942c4aa0220587350e7db1f4380a36ebb441906833563d32a62c4a>03cf334295615f981c47e";
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a.split("/")));
```

Result

```
[200, 23, Ne7WoRK, 3045022100d62568e28cb58b4a5308750e63e4690c4538ddc18>a9dc6075d02f7b4f942c4aa0220587350e7db1f4380a36ebb441906833563d32a62c4a>03cf334295615f981c47e]
```

And then do some other work to get the wanted requirement

Answer (score 1):

Try this: `(\d+)\/(?:.+)\/(.+)\/(.+)`

It'll give you 3 groups containing the 3 strings.

The Java code for this would be:

```
Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("(\d+)\/(?:.+)\/(.+)\/(.+)").matcher(yourString);
if (matcher.find()) {
    String bid = matcher.group(1);
    String username = matcher.group(2);
    String signature = matcher.group(3);
} else {
    // Malformed String
}
```

Comment: You should use `matcher.match()` instead of `matcher.find()`, to catch more invalid strings.

Answer (score 0):

You can group the expressions by using ( )
for example you'd have 3 groupings.

```
^([\d]*)\/([\d]*)\/([a-zA-Z|0-9]*)
```

- Group 1: Digits
- Group 2: Digits
- Group 3: Alpha & Digits

Answer (score 0):

You could split on matching either a forward slash, 1+ digits and a forward slash or just a forward slash using an [alternation](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html):

```
/\d+/|/
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/BnRyTg/1) | [Java demo](https://ideone.com/qxuzBl)

For example:

```
String regex = "/\\d+/|/";
String string = "200/23/Ne7WoRK/3045022100d62568e28cb58b4a5308750e63e4690c4538ddc18>a9dc6075d02f7b4f942c4aa0220587350e7db1f4380a36ebb441906833563d32a62c4a>03cf334295615f981c47e";
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(string.split(regex)));
```

Result:

```
[200, Ne7WoRK, 3045022100d62568e28cb58b4a5308750e63e4690c4538ddc18>a9dc6075d02f7b4f942c4aa0220587350e7db1f4380a36ebb441906833563d32a62c4a>03cf334295615f981c47e]
```